# Why is my Rails app returning "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)" when I have the correct amount of characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch, bcrypt-ruby

I am building a simple registration page.

Here is my User model with it's validations, and associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
    has_many :likes

    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Here is my User migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest
      t.integer :age
      t.integer :years_in_the_labor
      t.string :title
      t.string :location
      t.string :ministry

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is also my User controller create method:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(name: params[:name], title: params[:title], username: params[:username], password: [:password])

    if @user.valid?
        @user.save
        render json: { status: 200, user: @user }
    else
        render json: { status: 401, message: @user.errors.full_messages }
    end
end
```

I am sending the params through `fetch`, here's what the params are:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Test Name User", "title"=>"Test Title User", "username"=>"test_username_user", "password"=>"password123", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create", "user"=>{"name"=>"Test Name User", "username"=>"test_username_user", "title"=>"Test Title User"}} permitted: false>
```

And I get this error:

```
message: ["Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]
```

My password validation is not working, although I pass the correct amount of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing to User.new just [:password] instead of params[:password]

it is most often used to pass parameters only a private function like this:

```
private

def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :title, :username, :password)
end
```

And then in your create method:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

**Update**

And instead of asking if the user is valid you can directly check if the user was saved

```
if @user.save
  # your code for success
else
  # your code for failure
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your password missed `params[:password]`

```
@user = User.new(name: params[:name], title: params[:title], username: params[:username], password: params[:password])
```

As it doesn't match any password, it is blank, which is something less than 6 characters.